# How to change Perl location for /usr/bin/env

Tags: linux, debian

I'm working on an older Debian 6 machine. It had an old version of Perl and it was causing some self tests to fail with *"Test::More version 0.96 required"*. I downloaded the latest Perl 5.22.1, built it from sources and placed it at `/opt/perl/`.

I have a script that use Perl, and its preamble is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

However, when I execute the script, it is using the old Perl instead of the new Perl. This is kind of expected because `/usr/bin/env` does not know about Perl (or I don't believe it does).

How do I tell `env` that Perl is the one in `/opt/perl/`, and not `/usr/bin/`? If possible, I'd like it to be a machine configuration (i.e., applies to everyone), and not a user configuration (i.e., applies to just me).

---

Here is the manpage for `env(1)`. There's not much to it, and I don't believe it discusses registering a new version of a program for an interpreter. There are no man pages for `env(7)` (miscellaneous) or `env(8)` (administration).

```
ENV(1)                           User Commands                          ENV(1)

NAME
       env - run a program in a modified environment

SYNOPSIS
       env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]

DESCRIPTION
       Set each NAME to VALUE in the environment and run COMMAND.

       -i, --ignore-environment
              start with an empty environment

       -0, --null
              end each output line with 0 byte rather than newline

       -u, --unset=NAME
              remove variable from the environment

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit

       A mere - implies -i.  If no COMMAND, print the resulting environment.

AUTHOR
       Written by Richard Mlynarik and David MacKenzie.

...
```

Comment: As a temporary measure you can try renaming perl binary in /bin and replace it with simlink to the one in /opt to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Like shell, `env` **uses `$PATH`** to find the executable file for a simple command name. (Unlike shell it doesn't try aliases, functions, and builtins first.) I don't have Debian at hand, but on my Ubuntu 14.04 (which shouldn't be much different) standard/packaged `perl` is in `/usr/bin`, and a test user with no customization gets a `$PATH` setting of

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

plus the default `.profile` checks if `$HOME/bin` exists and if so adds it at the front.

`/usr/local/*` is intended precisely for "specific to my system" overrides, and `~username/bin` for "this user only" overrides, so a symlink in any of them should work. Alternatively you could put `/opt/perl` (or maybe `/opt/perl/bin` if it's structured that way) in your `$PATH` prior to `/usr/bin`.

Comment: *"`/usr/local/\*` is intended precisely for "specific to my system" overrides..."* - the problem here is Perl pollutes the directory it touches. Its one thing if it installs one or two programs, a few libs, etc. But Perl sprays stuff all over the directories it touches. Its one of the reasons I did not want to use `/usr/local`.